# Connection refused when running docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel, docker

I'm getting PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused") when running docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate on the terminal

here's my db config on .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=172.20.0.4
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=queue_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

I also inspect the container ip

docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' worker-db

Output: 172.20.0.4

here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:

#PHP Service
app:
    build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    image: digitalocean.com/php
    container_name: worker-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    environment:
    SERVICE_NAME: app
    SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker/config/php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    networks:
    - app-network

#Nginx Service
webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: worker-webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
    - "8090:80"
    - "443:443"
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    - ./docker/config/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
    - app-network

#MySQL Service
db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: worker-db
    # restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: queue_db
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    SERVICE_TAGS: dev
    SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
    - app-network

#Docker Networks
networks:
app-network:
    driver: bridge

#Volumes
volumes:
dbdata:
    driver: local
```

There's a weird error on the stack trace where ip is different i'm not sure why it's getting a different ip, but in my .env file i'm using the container ip which is "172.20.0.4"

```
Exception trace:
1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
  /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=172.20.0.3;port=3306;dbname=queue_db", "root", "root", [])
  /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also tried to delete the clear the cache using artisan command 
docker-compose exec app php artisan cache:clear. but no luck

Comment: Try this, run  ```ifconfig``` on your terminal and then look for ```inet```  which would be something like 192.168.1.4. You should use that ip address as DB_HOST

Answer (score 0):

ok, after i tried to run php artisan config:clear it's working now.